# neo4j in JEE (JBoss) environment:

Tags: java, rest, maven, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have built a RESTful web service for Wildfly using Neo4j OGM, but when I access it I get a `NullPointerException`.
It seems that a `Map` that should be populated with my model classes has not been initialized by the time it is accessed. Why is this happening?

Upfront I have to say that this module, `salessupport-ui`, is currently implemented as a fat client using javafx and it works fine connecting to the neo4j community edition 2.2.4, reading, writing, no problem.
What I would like to do now and this is where I face problems, I want to use wildfly as a server which itself connects to neo4j, thus that the javafx client application sends requests only to the wildfly server.
The protocol which I decided to use is REST, the implementation which is already kind-of provided on wildfly is resteasy.

Below are 1) the exception and some debugging info, 2) details about my context, project structure and the code for my classes.

## 1. Problem

Here are the exception and my findings when debugging.

### Exception

Now when I call this REST service by entering http://localhost:8080/salessupport-restsvc/rest/address/list in the browser, the following exception is raised:

```
00:07:38,458 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /salessupport-restsvc/rest/address/list: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData.entityType(MetaData.java:231)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.entityType(Neo4jSession.java:451)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:55)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:94)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:114)
at groupid.salessupport.db.core.ApplicationContext$GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(ApplicationContext.java:74)
at groupid.salessupport.restsvc.impl.SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl.java:29)
at groupid.salessupport.restsvc.impl.AddressRestImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.findAll(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
... 32 more
```

### Debugging info

- By debugging I can see that it goes, as expected, to my first breakpoint in class `SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl`, method `findAll()` calling `repository.findAll();`
- 2nd also expected, it goes to the inner `GraphRepositoryImpl` class to method `findAll(...)` and line `context.getSession().loadAll(clazz);` which creates a `Session`.
- A few steps later it tries in `org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData` class in method `_classInfo(String,String,String)` to call `domainInfo.getClassInfosWithAnnotation(nodeEntityAnnotation);` where `nodeEntityAnnotation="org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity"`.
- In the `DomainInfo` class method `getClassInfosWithAnnotation` which is then invoked the map `annotationNameToClassInfo` is empty. I expect it to be filled with my models, which obviously happens in the javafx environment, but not in the JavaEE env.

here is that method

```
public List<ClassInfo> getClassInfosWithAnnotation(String annotation) {
    return annotationNameToClassInfo.get(annotation);
}
```

For checking, if the REST mechanism works as is I put a class next to the AddressRestImpl>

```
@Path("dummy")
public class DummyImpl {
    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Amount> getAll() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Amount());
    }
}
```

Calling this in the browser by navigating to http://localhost:8080/salessupport-restsvc/rest/dummy/list results in the expected: [{"amount":null,"currency":null}]

I have plenty of simple stuff to improve here, I have tried quite a lot of approaches, also on Tomcat 8 the same exception happens, but there the Rest approach did not work even in the dummy case so I switched to wildfly.
Did I find a bug here or is there something simply I have missed in my setup?

## 2) Project and Code Details

Here is information about my environment, project structure and the code I run when I have this problem.

### Environment

My environment is as follows:

I have Neo4J community edition 2.2.4.

I downloaded wildfly-9.0.1.Final and, except for a management port which conflicted with my NVidia Driver Software I left everything untouched.

### Project Structure

I have a maven multimodule application which consists of the following modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>salessupport-ui</module>
    <module>salessupport-intf</module>
    <module>salessupport-db</module>
    <module>salessupport-restsvc</module>
</modules>
```

The dependencies are as follows:

```
salessupport-intf <-- salessupport-db
                          ^
                          |-- salessupport-ui
                          |-- salessupport-restsvc
```

#### Dependencies

Let me explain the dependencies:

salessupport parent has a dependency management definition like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

salessupport-intf uses the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

salessupport-restsvc `pom.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>salessupport</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>salessupport-restsvc</artifactId>
<name>salessupport-restsvc</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.11.Final</resteasy.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>salessupport-intf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>salessupport-db</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery,
                    org.neo4j.server.rest.web
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

### Code

Here are the relevant classes.

#### `GraphRepository` interface

I defined my custom GraphRepository interface:

```
public interface GraphRepository<S> {

    Iterable<S> findAll(Iterable<Long> nodeIds);

    Iterable<S> findAll();

    void delete(S arg0);

    S save(S arg0);

}
```

#### Model Classes

There are some model classes, e.g.:

```
package groupid.salessupport.db.model;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity(label="Amount")
public class Amount {

    @GraphId Long id;

    private Double amount;

    private Currency currency;

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new DecimalFormat().format(amount)+" "+currency;
    }

}
```

and

```
@NodeEntity(label="Currency")
public class Currency extends BaseObject {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

#### Generic Simple Rest Graph Repository interface

```
public interface ISimpleRestGraphRepository<T> {
    @DELETE
    @Path("delete")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void delete(T arg0);

    @PUT
    @Path("save")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public T save(T arg0);

    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Iterable<T> findAll();

    @POST
    @Path("listbyids")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<Long> arg0);
}
```

#### REST Interface Definition for Amount

```
@Path("amount")
public interface AmountRest extends ISimpleRestGraphRepository<Amount> {
}
```

#### REST Activator

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}
```

#### Generic implementation of my REST Service

```
@RequestScoped
public class SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl<T> implements ISimpleRestGraphRepository<T> {

    private final GraphRepository<T> repository;

    public SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl(GraphRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T arg0) {
        repository.delete(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T arg0) {
        return repository.save(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<T> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<Long> arg0) {
        return repository.findAll(arg0);
    }

}
```

#### ... and the specific Implementation for Address:

```
public class AmountRestImpl extends SimpleRestGraphRepositoryImpl<Amount> implements AmountRest {

    public AmountRestImpl() {
        super(NeoRepositories.getInstance().getAmountRepository());
    }

}
```

#### DB Connection

in salessupport-db we connect to the database with some code:

```
public class ApplicationContext {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session openSession;

    public ApplicationContext() {

    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("groupid.salessupport.db.model");
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        if (openSession == null) {
            openSession = getSessionFactory().openSession("http://localhost:7474",
                    "username", "password"); // it is not really like this     
    }
        return openSession;
    }

    public <S,G extends GraphRepository<S>> GraphRepository<S> getGraphRepository(Class<S> clazz) {
        return new GraphRepositoryImpl<S>(this, clazz);
    }

    public static class GraphRepositoryImpl<S> implements GraphRepository<S> {
        private ApplicationContext context;
        private Class<S> clazz;

        public GraphRepositoryImpl(ApplicationContext context, Class<S> clazz) {
            this.context = context;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<S> findAll(Iterable<Long> nodeIds) {
            List<Long> listNodeIds;
            if (nodeIds instanceof List) {
                listNodeIds = (List<Long>) nodeIds;
            } else {
                listNodeIds = new LinkedList<>();
                for (Long l : nodeIds) {
                    listNodeIds.add(l);
                }
            }
            return context.getSession().loadAll(clazz,listNodeIds);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<S> findAll() {
            return context.getSession().loadAll(clazz);
        }

        @Override
        public void delete(S arg0) {
            Session session = context.getSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            context.getSession().delete(arg0);
            transaction.commit();
            transaction.close();
        }

        @Override
        public S save(S arg0) {
            Session session = context.getSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(arg0);
            transaction.commit();
            transaction.close();
            return arg0;
        }

    }

}
```

#### Usage

Implementors acquire an instance of this `GraphRepository` quick and dirty with a "singleton":

```
public class NeoRepositories {
private ApplicationContext context;

private static final NeoRepositories INSTANCE = new NeoRepositories();

private NeoRepositories() {
    context = new ApplicationContext();
}

public GraphRepository<Person> getPersonRepository() {
    return context.getGraphRepository(Person.class);
}

public static NeoRepositories getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

public GraphRepository<Amount> getAmountRepository() {
    return context.getGraphRepository(Amount.class);
}
...
}
```

P.S.: It is my first question on stackoverflow, I hope I wrote as little and as much as necessary to convey the problem ...

Comment: I think this is a little bit too much :D
Start by explaining your exception and the error, and give the details later, as needed.

Comment: I thought the more necessary details I give, the better the answers will be.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Details are great, but it was a bit overwhelming to read and your question got lost in between code that is only meaningful once the question is understood. I have tried to edit your question to put the actual question on top as well as structure and reorder the details. Please verify that I didn't loose anything, and feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Also, the method that throws the `NullPointerException`, is it part of `neo4j-ogm`? If so, that seems important and may be worth emphasizing more.

Comment: Thank you for all the details- it would be very helpful if you had this code available somewhere (github?). That would allow us to get to the bottom of this quicker. +1 to @jjaderberg for his advice to highlight the NullPointerException from neo4j ogm

Comment: With log level INFO for org.neo4j.ogm, you should see messages like these upon startup. Please share the number of classes loaded. For example
2015-09-10 13:50:14,162  INFO o4j.ogm.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor: 159 - Post-processing complete
2015-09-10 13:50:14,162  INFO o4j.ogm.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor:  61 - 6 classes loaded in 12 milliseconds

Comment: 01:02:37,022 INFO  [org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.info.ClassFileProcessor] (default task-3) 0 classes loaded in 1146 milliseconds

Comment: Is there a chance to manually add the models to the DomainInfo?

Comment: Thanks for all the effort for reformatting and rearranging the question and for asking for clarifications. @Luanne I made an MCVE and put it on github, as mentioned aboce. Unlike my problem here I put all classes in one module so we can neglect inter-module dependencies.  The single maven project can be found at http://github.com/mkirchmann/mcve-neo4j-jee-rest.git

Comment: The virtual file system used by Wildfly messes up the class scanning done by the OGM. Opened https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/48 to track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/48 there has been an update, which has been implemented with neo4j-ogm version >2 .

I made the whole sourcecode available on https://github.com/mkirchmann/hello-neo4j-ogm , No guarantee that everything is working or all is correct, at least listing the whole nodes for one type should be possible. And **don't forget to set up ogm.properties correctly**.

The key for the solution is the **vfs driver** for neo4j-ogm, which can be found in https://github.com/mkirchmann/neo4j-ogm-resourceresolver-vfs (it has been forked from ctpconsulting, use version 2.1.1 and mvn install in order to make it available in your local maven repository)

### pom.xml

The following pom.xml is setting up the necessary (maybe more, not sure), so that a Rest call can be made successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.neuenberger</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloNeo4jOgmOnWildFly</name>
<description>Very Simple configuration to use neo4j ogm on WildFly application server</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <neo4jogmversion>2.1.1</neo4jogmversion>
    <resteasy.version>3.1.1.Final</resteasy.version>
    <version.war.plugin>3.0.0</version.war.plugin>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ctp.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-resourceresolver-vfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4jogmversion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4jogmversion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery,
                    org.neo4j.server.rest.web
                </packagingExcludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j</id>
        <name>Neo4j</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

**Thanks for everyones contribution and support!**

Answer (score 0):

Is this [@NodeEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/NodeEntity.html) from [Spring Data Neo4j](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j)? If yes, Spring must be setup correctly, which I cannot find here.

Comment: I use org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity

Comment: The project setup is not using Spring. It is using neo4j-ogm.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675002/entity-is-not-an-instance-of-a-persistable-class-neo4j-4-0-0